# SF novel - Space adventure with a single human traveling the galaxy looking for answers

Tags: story-identification, novel

The time period is near-future pre-interstellar, think Expanse tech level.

1. Man finds an artifact in the ice on one of the outer planets' moons. It’s an ancient machine stuck in the ice.
2. The intelligence of the Machine takes over his mind and uses him to stop another intelligence from destroying the Earth.  Then it hijacks his spaceship and makes him the first interstellar traveler.  He ends up on a massive alien space station.  That is the end of the first book.
3. The second book is on the space station inhabited by aliens from all over.  He believes they were hijacked like himself and have been living there for generations.
4. There might be a third book where they help aquatic aliens.

Comment: Hi! Do you have any idea of when the books were published? When did you read them? Were they thick or thin novels? Do you remember any details about the covers? Any information will help.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the first book (I haven't read the others) sounds like [Neptune Crossing](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/590747.Neptune_Crossing), first book of the Chaos Chronicles by Jeffrey A. Carver.

Comment: That sounds about right. I read book 2 and remember the protagonist traveling through the space station and noticing many vessels full of volatile materials, some of which later wound up exploding due to some sort of enemy action.